# Compile ClojureScript excluding Closure Library from Artifact

Tags: leiningen, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript, google-closure

I am just  getting started with ClojureScript, and I would like to mix and match completely unrelated ClojureScript applications on different pages at runtime. I understand leinigen compilation is designed to squeeze all code needed for on app in one JavaScript file. To keep things separated, I would like to have the Closure library separated from the application - even if that prevents some of the optimizations.

Is it possible to compile ClojureScript excluding the Closure library from the final JavaScript artifact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can use closure-library in an uncompiled state, but you cannot directly exclude it without resorting to creating a new library which exports all of your methods.

For related answers, see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28281505/1211524
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10401030/1211524

Comment: Well in fact it looks like this could generally be done using closure library modules, but it seems the ClojureScript compiler does not support it yet.